# Why can't you add IOException() object to a collection of "? extends Exception"?

Tags: java, inheritance, exception

Consider the following list:

```
List<? extends Exception> errLst = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now consider the object:

```
IOException err = new IOException();
```

Why can't I add err to errLst, even though err is an instance of Exception? As far as I know, errLst should accept any object which inherits from Exception class (upper bound).

I also noticed that the following code, in contrary to the previous code, works:

```
List<? super Exception> errLst2 = new ArrayList<>();
errLst.add(new IOException());
```

However, to the best of my knowledge, errLst2 should only accept types Exception inherits **from** (lower bound).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it already has an answer at [stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/303584/what-is-the-difference-between-extends-foo-and-foo)

Comment: `List<? super Exception> errLst = new ArrayList<>();` works fine. It also surprised me, maybe we misunderstood the meaning of `? extends Exception`(Exactly the opposite)...

Comment: Because you cannot add literally aanything to `Collection<? extends Anything>`. Thats because you don't know what ? is and you are guaranteed that every element is of type ? - thus you cannot risk breaking contract - thus you are disallow to even try to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the nature of generics.

`errList` contains *some specific type* which is `Exception` or a subtype of it. But it is not known if that specific type is actually `IOException`, it could be also `RuntimeException`, for instance.

That's why the compiler does not let you add an `IOException`.

---

#### When to use wildcards?

Wildcards are there for if you want to denote that the type parameter really doesn't matter. For example, if I were to write a method popping off the last element of some list, the type of elements really doesn't matter.

```
public static void popOffLastElement(List<?> list) {
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        int lastIndex = list.size() - 1;
        list.remove(lastIndex);
    }
}
```

#### Do we *need* wildcards?

Well, we could achieve the same with a type parameter:

```
public static <T> void popOffLastElement(List<T> list) {
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        int lastIndex = list.size() - 1;
        list.remove(lastIndex);
    }
}
```

So strictly speaking, the wildcard is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add `err` object for the same reason as you cannot add an `Object` in below scenario

```
List<?> errLst = new ArrayList<>();
errLst.add(new Object());
```

Reason : We don't know what is the specific type `errLst` is pointing to. In your case, it can be `Exception,IOException,EOFException etc`. In above case `errLst` could be pointing of any class that has been declared .`? extends T` is called covariance and normally variable are declared in this way to `get` elements for it, not add elements.

If you have a scenario where you want to add elements to a `List` objects, you should use `Contravariance(? super T)`. Changing your code to below will resolve any error that you are getting

```
List<? super Exception> errLst = new ArrayList<>();
```

This a [link](https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance) where it is beautifully explained [what is Covariance and Contravariance In Java](https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance). Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This expression on his own will never work:

```
List<? extends Exception> errLst = new ArrayList<>();
```

The reason is that you are creating a list of error which subclass Exception, without saying which type is ... so no type will ever fit the definition.

You can use  to assign a specific list to that one ...

You create a list of specific Exceptions (in this case IOException).

```
List<IOException> ioErrors = new ArrayList<IOException>();
IOException e = new IOException();
ioErrors.add(e);
```

Later you can assign ioErrors to your error list and use it.

```
List<? extends Exception> errLst = ioErrors;

for (Exception exception : errLst) {

}
```

But you will never be able to add errors to your errList.